# How to use argparse library to parse a given string instead of app_args?

Tags: python, string, overriding, argparse

I have tried to run below code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--target", required=True)
parsed_args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(args = ["--target foobar"])
print(parsed_args.target)
```

but I get error saying that `following arguments are required: --target`.
I haven't passed any arguments when running python script, I want to just pass a string to the parser during runtime but it seems to still expect arguments when running the file.

Comment: you are passing "--target foobar"  as single argument but you should be passing it as ["--target","foobar"]

Comment: @rasjani if i pass more than one element in that list then i get `ValueError: to many values to unpack (expected 1)`.
Could you post an example if that works for you?

Comment: The official doc for `argparse` has many `parse_args` examples.  Some use the `--foo bar'.split()` form, but more (and eventually all) use `['--foo', 'bar']` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--target", required=True)
parsed_args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(args = ["--target","foobar"]) # this array is the only change to your code
print(parsed_args.target)
```

and in repr things look like this;

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("--target", required=True)
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--target'], dest='target', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=True, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parsed_args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(args = ["--target","foobar"])
>>> print(parsed_args.target)
foobar
>>>
```

So dunno where you are getting your `ValueError` exception.

Comment: works both ways for me.. different python interpreter ?

Comment: my bad, I had a very silly mistake. thanks